# sorting of the vector

Tags: c++, sorting, stl

ALL,
I have the following problem.

Consider following class:

```
class A
{
public:
.....
private:
    int m_a, m_b;
    double m_c;
};
```

and I have a vector of objects of this class.

This vector is presented in the grid to the user and (s)he can click on the column header to sort the elements of the grid (vector).
The problem comes from the fact that the user can press and hold CTRL key and click the row header in which case the grid (vector) should be sorted by 2 columns (members of the class).

I can write a simple sorter class which will do sorting based on the one member (column) but I don't really understand how to pick up the second sorting column and do sorting.

Can someone please help?

Comment: To start with, you might want to read about [`std::sort`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/sort). And if your compiler is new enough, maybe read about [lambda functions](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lambda).

Comment: Easily done a number of ways. Do you know what a functor or lambda is? You need one for each method of sorting you want, then use it as the comparator for [`std::sort`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/sort). Examples on how to use default sorting as well as custom-sorting (what you need) are at the provided link for `std::sort`.

Comment: As for a more concrete help with your problem, a very simple solution is to have seven different sort functions, one for each combination of the three variables.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg: It's actually every permutation of the three variables. (It could be every subset of every permutation, but you can put the unspecified columns at the end of the permutation without loss of generality, so "only" n! is enough. If n is 3, that's slightly less than 2^n-1, but in the general case its quite a lot more.

Comment: All, please my see reply to rici.

Answer (score 2):

The simplest way to do this is to sort by each column in turn, starting with the least significant column. So if the user chooses sort by `a then b then c`, then you first sort by `c`, then you sort by `b`, and finally you sort by `a`. The last two sorts (`b` and `a`) must be a *stable sort* (`std::stable_sort`), which preserves the existing order for otherwise equal elements.

The other way of doing it -- which is almost certainly faster but might not be practical -- is to use a custom compare function. But coming up with the custom compare function is not easy. In the example you provide, where there are only three variables, then there are only six possible compare functions (one for each ordering of a,b,c -- you can put the unspecified columns at the end) but in the general case you end up with too many possibilities to enumerate. You could use a complicated collection of switch statements to write a general comparator, but the overhead of that comparator may well turn out to be more than sorting the vector multiple times.

Comment: Unfortunately this class contain a lot more than 3 members - 64 to be exact. So in order to satisfy the requirements I will need 2^64 combination. I don't think its even feasible to write that many. Any simpler solution? Thank you.

Comment: @igor: yes, the way I suggest in the first paragraph. (And it's not 2^64, it's 64!, which is even larger.)

Comment: @Igor Apart from the solution suggested by rici, you may want to keep an array of function pointers (to member functions, for example) and assemble your comparator function from these functions. This is a whole lot easier than having a "complicated collection of switch statements", but basically does the same thing. If performance is one of your main concerns, I would consider implementing both approaches.

Comment: And by the way, STL already offers stable sort, `std::stable_sort`.

Comment: @Markus Mayr, could you put some pseudocode please? Also it is possible to sort in ascending and descending modes. And at times I will need to save the sorting, resort the vector to pick some data and then sort back. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Since you asked to provide code that dynamically creates a suitable comparison function ...

Disclaimer: The following code probably is not comparable to sorting the vector multiple times with a stable sorting algorithm like `std::stable_sort` in terms of performance. It is only supposed to illustrate an idea. The following code is written using `C++11` features, which may not be available to you yet. It can, however, easily be rewritten in `C++03` using, for example, `boost`.

Let's assume that you have your class `A` and some getter functions for each member variable:

```
class A
{
    public:
        float getA() const;
        int getB() const;
        // and so on.
};
```

We are going to define functions that are returning `-1`, if one instance of `A` is smaller than the other one, `0`, if they are equal and `1` otherwise. These functions can be combined more easily.

```
using comparator = std::function<int (const A&, const A&)>;

template <class T>
comparator
make_comparator( T (A::*f)() const )
{
    return [f]( const A& lhs, const A& rhs ) -> int {
        if( (lhs.*f)() < (rhs.*f)() )
            return -1;
        else if( (lhs.*f)() == (rhs.*f)() )
            return 0;
        else
            return 1;
    };
}
```

Now, for each member function we are defining a `comparator`:

```
std::vector<comparator> comparators = {
    make_comperator( &A::getA ), make_comparator( &A::getB )
};
```

We can easily combine comparator functions:

```
comparator
make_comparator(
    const std::vector<comparator> &comparators,
    std::deque<unsigned int> indices )
{
    if( indices.empty() )
    {
        return []( const A&, const A& ) -> int { return 0; };
    }
    unsigned int first = indices.front();
    indices.pop_front();
    return [first, &comparators, indices]( const A& lhs, const A& rhs ) -> int {
        int firstCompared = comparators[first]( lhs, rhs );
        if( firstCompared != 0 )
        {
            return firstCompared;
        }
        else
        {
            return make_comparator( comparators, indices )( lhs, rhs );
        }
    };
}
```

These functions can be converted to a `less`-like functor:

```
std::function<bool (const A&, const A&)>
to_less( std::function<int( const A&, const A& )> f )
{
    return [&f]( const A& lhs, const A& rhs ) -> bool {
        return f( lhs, rhs ) < 0;
    };
}
```

Sorting after first, than second column:

```
std::sort( instances.begin(), instances.end(),
            to_less( make_comparator( comparators, { 0, 1 } ) ) );
```